# Help to understand on atcoder Math problem statement

Tags: problem-solving

I stumble on this question (https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc116/tasks/abc116_c) and I cannot for my life understand what the problem ask me to solve

So I understand these part:
we have N flowers
each flowers start at 0 heights
we have sequences of heights that map to each flowers.
I know there could be some sort of addition in here because on the third sample, I can see 96+50+75 = 221.

What I didn't understand
what is the relation of these "l" and "r" to the problem? I know r should be equal to the number of flower but in the first output, "r" can be 3.

I just cannot understand the problem, even after looking up the answer, I still don't know why the answer like that.

Answer (score 1):

The $l$ and $r$ are indices. The input $(1,3)$ indicates that flowers number $1,2,3$ should be increased by $1$. If I instead input $(5,19)$, then flowers $5$ to $19$ are increased by $1$. So $r$ is not the number of flowers. Instead, if there are $n$ flowers, then we have to have $1 \leq l \leq r \leq n$.

Comment: Thanks, I think I start to see it.    

So for sample first input output, they do  
- (1,3) so it will be "1 1 1 0" 
- then they do (2,4) to make it "1 2 2 1". 

and for the second input 
(1,5) then (1,1) twice then (3,4) then (4,4) assuming l and r can be less than or equal. 

The description of (l,r) in the problem might need little more explanation